# Objective-C header file not found (AFNetworking.h)

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, podfile

```
#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>
```

I imported AFNetworking.h file to .m file but an error occurred like this:

> 'AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h' file not found

I deleted pods folder and Podfile.lock, and reinstalled Podfile but didn't solved. What should I do? (I opened the workspace file.)

Comment: Is library search paths/framework search paths updated correctly?

Comment: @Satheesh There is "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.framework/Headers" in Header Search Paths, but is it right to find it here?

Comment: I resolved it by running in an actual device, not in a simulator... Why did it become duplicated question? The answers of those questions are not an answer of this.

Answer (score 1):

**Linking !== Copying.**

there is C style `#include ...` and Objective-C style `#import ...`

both work almost the same..
where **#import** reads the header but does not include again if done once. As this can and does fail sometime (usually because mixing C,C++,Objc,Objc++ in different dialects) we often use `#define` rules to make sure the enclosed code is read once for sure and **not** again, which in turn works also when code is included and declared with **#include**. It would be included but not compiled twice.

```objectivec
#ifndef SOME_HumanReadableFlag_h
#define SOME_HumanReadableFlag_h

// ... your header code here..
@interface XyzObject : FromInheritedClass

@end

#endif
```

Now why does it matter?
It might happen that a #define rule enclosing the header files content hides the header from the viewpoint of other classes.. This can & does happen often when classes are not properly written with the end developers structure in mind. It might work on the workbench of the developer but not for everyone else implementing it.

Your error clearly tells "`File not found ..`"
So first see what both import/include rules differentiate in general

1. `#import <LibFrameworkName/LibFrameworkName.h>`
   means you have to link the framework or library, even if you developed one on your own in that project. The rule is relative to your project, LibFrameworkName is a Framework/Lib. 
   Where if found somewhere *#include <LibFrameworkName/LibFrameworkName.h>* is not correct unless you want to c-style include this framework header into your binarys header, 2) tells you a bit about why..
2. `#import "LibFrameworkName/LibFrameworkName.h"`
   means you have to copy/offer this header into your project with a subfolder with name LibFrameworkName. Once somewhere declared properly Xcode might find and apply the headers even if declared with the wrong rule later on in that specific class, you should also get a warning in the IDE then. In case of AFNetworking you dont want to copy System SDK Frameworks into your project, also not into third party frameworks unless you know what you do. This rule is relative to the files place in project structure, meaning here it would try to look out for some folder with name *LibFrameworkName* below the file that carries this rule.

**what it says:** because the Framework is not linked, the compiler tries to find it with the given name ignoring `<` & `>` so as if it where like 2) a file with that folder name, then will not find it and throws the error or warning.

To force the precompiler to parse thru some specific folders we use sometime the **header search path** to explicit tell where to find it. Widely used and mostly troublesome because it also hides wrongly defined rules to the developer as Xcode skips the still existing wrong import rules in code assuming it knows this headers already. Or it throws warnings while everything is actually fine. Other developers experience trouble then, the file structure and header list don't match at all. So keep in mind, when you can avoid making use of header search path lists, go for it. It also will and should not fix your issue.

> `'<AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>' File not found` means a Framework module is not known to your project. This header is part of a Framework.

**Solution:** You have to go to your **Projects Settings** and scroll down to **Frameworks and Libraries**, hit [+] below this list. It should open the dialog presenting all SDK from your choosen Project Target and all known Pods or known frameworks of your own project when you developed some. Search for the Framework or Lib by name, click it, hit "Add".. done..

From there - there are some options to get used to it..
***Because Linking does not mean Copying*** into your Resources at compile time by default. Usually Xcode knows it does not have to copy System SDK into a projects Framework Folder, all macUsers have those Frameworks preinstalled on their system of course in the right version.. Linking against some specific folder like `${SOMEFLAGWHEREEVERTHISPOINTSTO}/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.framework/Headers` is actually wrong unless someone wanted to overrule the systems framework header and maybe also binary.

So `AFNetworking` should not appear under **Build Phases** > **Copy Bundle Ressources** list but after the process above is done it will appear under **Link Binary with Libraries**, it might also be placed in **Dependencies** when Xcode needs to know for some Library/Framework it must have this to compile. Last mentioned option is because you could have a framework that adapts at runtime when some framework is missing or not available. So this Entry helps Xcode to figure out in which sorting it has to compile your stuff.

finding `${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.framework/Headers` in **Header Search Paths** there must be something wrong i guess.. because the framework is very likely not copied into the Pods folder. It should be relative to your SDKs folder that come with Xcode. The Linking process told above should fix that and you can erase that entry from your header search path then.